# Use multiple Guava versions in same maven project

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, guava

I have the following two dependencies in my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.javascript</groupId>
  <artifactId>closure-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>v20141215</version>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
          <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As you can see in the dependency tree, they both contain a different version of Guava:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ extraction ---

[INFO] +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20141215:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler-externs:jar:v20141215:compile
[INFO] |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7:system
[INFO] |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 18.0)
[INFO] |  +- ...
```

The well known problem is that Guava is not backward compatible. Therefore I kind of need both jars.

The error - I get - is the following:

```
Error:  tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat
```

This has already reported here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10961

Moreover they suggest to handle it by using the shading Maven plugin:
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/d5_HqUSvVl4

Which I tried here:

```
<build>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
            <target>1.6</target> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>project.shaded.com.google</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

But I still get the same error.

Can anyone help me with this Maven issue?

Thank you,
Felix

Comment: did you get this solved?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest finding the latest version of Guava that functions with Hadoop 2.4 and including that as an explicit dependency. Then exclude Guava from being fetched transiently from the closure compiler and Hadoop deps.

I'd suggest v16 as that still has the zero-args constructor on the StopWatch class: see [Guava 16](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.java?name=v16.0.1)

Of course this solution depends on Guava 16 working with the closure compiler.

Comment: That's the problem. The closure package needs Guava 18

Comment: v20140303 only requires Guava 16.  Even if a version is specified it may not necessarily be an absolute requirement.

Comment: I really want to use the latest version :(

Comment: Why do you want to use the latest version? You seem to "want", not "need". Guava version 16.0.1 is rather complete compared to the current version. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release17) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release18) are the latest version differences between 16 and 18, the current version. Do you really need any of those new features?

Comment: I want to use the latest version of the closure compiler. Because it is probably more stable and this is very important for my application. You are right about Guava^^

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look into the resulting JAR and see whether it's built correctly. Cleaning the local maven repo may solve the problem.

Comment: I cleaned the local maven repo and I can also find Guava classes in the corresponding folder of the jar^^